# DE not working after driver installation on Oracle Vm

Tags: drivers, virtualbox, 17.04, mate, budgie

I have been playing around with some Virtualbox Machines on my Ubuntu and installing Ubuntu Mate 17.04 and Ubuntu Budgie 17.04 on them testing out how those systems are. Budgie was pretty CPU intensive and I found out it is rendering the windows with my CPU (Xeon E3 1231v3, I gave it 4 of my 8 cores). So I installed the recommended proprietary virtualbox graphics adapter from Innotek wich screwed the System that much up that I could just login to the console, but before I can do this I have to press ALT + F4. I have retried the driver installation just in case I have done something wrong but the issue persisted. I do not think the RAM and VRAM is a problem, I gave it 6 GB RAM and 128Mb VRAM wich was the maximum I can give it, my PC should not have problems with this either, my GTX 1060 has 6GB VRAM. Later I found out that these driver also brake my Ubuntu Mate VM, but on Mate there is no need for those drivers so everything consuring this is ok I think.
Maybe the following might also help for solving my problem: When i boot up both the Mate Machine and the Budgie there is a message beeing displayed wich says

```
[     8.101523] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
```

Is there anything I can do so that I can use the desktop envirement with good performance? Thank you for your help in advance.

physical System:

- Xeon e3 1231v3
- 16 GB Ram
- Gigabyte Mainboard H97-D3H
- GTX 1060 6GB
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Nvdia binary driver 381.22 (open)
- Virtualbox v5.0.40

Comment: In a VM you don't access the real hardware, only the virtualized ones provided by the virtualization software. That's why you **don't** install Nvidia drivers in a VM and, for better support including the virtual graphics, install guest additions instead.

Comment: @MichaelBay I installed the graphics adapter, not the nvidia binaries. I thought maybe virtualbox would have a problem with my drivers that's why the physical specs are written down.

Comment: You don't install graphics drivers of any kind in a Virtualbox VM.

Comment: @MichaelBay Ah, I see. Are graphics adapters then needed?

Comment: Even if installed the usual way and using the real hardware, Ubuntu and most current Linux distros seldom need installation of additional drivers. Ubuntu in a VM already has support for all the virtualized hardware.

Comment: Looks like budgie has not. But yes, mate has. I see.

Comment: Did you try to install [VirtualBox Guest Additions](/q/22743/175814)? Those tend to improve the use of the graphics acceleration of the host system.